# running Selenium webdriver from Python console

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

This command entered in Python's interpreter opens a new FireFox window:

```
webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\\...\\geckodriver.exe').get('https://doesnmatter/')
```

But then when I want to locate elements, but this open another Firefox window:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*doesnmatter")
```

How do I locate elements in the first Firefox window from Python console?

Answer (score 1):

I have recreated your use case and tried a simple solution, 
First run the below command (assuming you have already imported neccessary libraries)

```
browser= webdriver.Firefox()
```

This command will launch a firefox instance. Once you have the "browser" object available, you can perform any action on this instance, for example,

```
browser.get("http://some_website.com")
ele_of_xpath=browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_of_the_element")
```

In this way you can keep performing activities using command line (in my case it is mac terminal) on the same browser instance.